# Hibernate Exception on MySQL Cross Join Query

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to perform a bulk delete of an object, Feature, which has a birdirectional ManyToOne relationship with another class, FeaturesMetadata. I'm having a SQLGrammerException thrown.

The hql I'm using:

```
String hql = "delete from Feature F where F.featuresMetadata.stateGeoId = :stateGeoId";
```

Turning on show SQL, the following is generated:

```
 delete from FEATURE cross join FEATURESMETADATA featuresme1_ where STATEGEOID=?
```

Running the SQL directly in the db client gives this exception:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cross join FEATURESMETADATA featuresme1_ where stategeoid='01'' at line 1
```

Since the generated SQL is throwing the Exception, I tried changing dialects from MySQL5InnoDBDialect to MySQLInnoDBDialect, but no change.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Does FeaturesMetaData have a FK to Feature?

Comment: Feature has a FK to FeaturesMetadata.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You may not have joins in such a HQL query. Quote from the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct):

> No joins, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL
>   query. Sub-queries can be used in the where-clause, where the
>   subqueries themselves may contain joins.

So I guess something like this should work:

```
delete from Feature F where F.id in 
    (select f2.id from Feature f2 where f2.featuresMetadata.stateGeoId = :stateGeoId)
```

Comment: Doh! I've read that several times and still didn't click. Answer accepted.

Comment: Hi, I'm surprised it worked for you since I'm getting: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: You can't specify target table 'Users' for update in FROM clause. It happens since  you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part  (in your case - the Feature table).
This behaviour is documented at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html. Any suggestions?

Comment: Wow. I thought HQL was about making queries more simplified and object-oriented than SQL. I don't see why Hibernate can't figure out on its own how to translate the relationship between the objects into an SQL query without an explicit join.

Comment: Can't understand how this answers to the main question: in the HQL he's not making any join...

Comment: @Phate He's doing an **implicit** join, you can see that Hibernate translates the query to a cross join.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and struggled to find a sensible answer. It seems that, even if you get this approach to work, the SQL generated is highly inefficient (according to what I have read).

So I took a step back and did the following:

```
    List<Properties> props = propDao.findPropertiesByHotelCode(hotel.getCode());
    propDao.deleteInBatch(props);
    propDao.flush();
```

Basically rather tan trying to 'delete where', I'm doing a select where and then deleting in batch the set that I retrieved.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed rather poor from Hibernate. But you can solve it like this in a repo: (at least in PostgreSQL, not sure if this syntax should be modified for MySql)

```
@Modifying
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = """
    DELETE FROM feature f
    USING features_metadata fd
    WHERE f.features_metadata_id = fd.id AND fd.state_geo_id = :stateGeoId
    """)
void deleteByStateGeoIdId(@Param("stateGeoId") UUID stateGeoId);
```