# JPA error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data and created the following query:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<User> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE FROM User u WHERE u.userDetails.userName = :username")
    public void deleteByUserName(@Param("username") String userName);
}
```

In runtime I keep on getting:

```
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cross join UserDetails userdetail1_ where User_Name='rb2x5yv7'' at line 1
```

I'm using MySql with MySQL5Dialect.

What is wrong with my query?

**

### UPDATE:

**

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246563/hibernate-exception-on-mysql-cross-join-query) thread I have changed my code:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<User> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE FROM User u WHERE u.id in (SELECT u1.id FROM User WHERE u1.userDetails.userName = :username)")
    public void deleteByUserName(@Param("username") String userName);
}
```

But now I'm getting:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [u1.id], unexpected token [u1] [DELETE FROM com.bs.dal.domain.User u WHERE u.id in (SELECT u1.id FROM com.bs.dal.domain.User WHERE u1.userDetails.userName = :username)]
```

**

### UPDATE 2:

**

It appears I was missing "u1" in the sub-query. Changed the query to:

```
 @Query("DELETE FROM User u WHERE u.id in (SELECT u1.id FROM User u1 WHERE u1.userDetails.userName = :username)")
```

Now I'm getting:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: You can't specify target table 'Users' for update in FROM clause.
```

I know it happens since you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.This behaviour is documented at: dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html.

How can I work it around? Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246563/hibernate-exception-on-mysql-cross-join-query

Comment: Thank you. Following your comment I have changed my code but still can't seem to make it work. Updating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work I had to do 2 things:

The first, using this query:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<User> {

    @Modifying
    @Query(name = "Delete User by UserName", value = "DELETE FROM User u WHERE u.id IN (SELECT ud.id FROM UserDetails ud WHERE ud.userName = :username)")
    public void deleteByUserName(@Param("username") String userName);
}
```

The second:

I have to make sure the delete-cascade is well implemented in the DB. For some reason, it was not generated automatically. You can see [my new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005442/on-delete-cascade-option-not-in-generated-when-using-ddl-schema-generation-on-my) that relates to this point.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to assign a table alias in a [DELETE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html) would be this:

```
DELETE u FROM User u WHERE u.userName = :username
       ^
```

Of course, if there's only one table involved, you can simply omit aliases:

```
DELETE FROM User WHERE userName = :username
```

Comment: Thanks Alvaro. Your suggestion is actually similar to my first attempt, but no joins, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL query, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246563/hibernate-exception-on-mysql-cross-join-query