# Java Hibernate HQL can't specify target table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql, named-query

I was reading the Post from user @JB Nizet

[Hibernate Exception on MySQL Cross Join Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246563/hibernate-exception-on-mysql-cross-join-query)

Later i have try my own code

I have a HQL like this.

```
update Student set newField='newField',anotherFieldsToBeUpdated where .... 
and id in
(select s.id from Student s where s.school=:school)
-->[Student->School]many to one relationship....
```

But still throws the infamous

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You can't specify target table 'Student' for update in FROM clause
```

I was wondering if still exists a solution without `using another different select` or use `a temporal table`.

Comment: Can you tell in words what is your query purpose? And what is the relationship between Student and School?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access just one and the same table you can combine your limitation together:

```
update Student set newField = :newField where ... and school = :school
```

Comment: Glad I could help. In case you need more info, refer to the [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) specification.