# Why hibernate generates cross join on delete?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 with Hibernate 5.2.10 and have 3 entities:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "entity1")
public class Entity1 {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity2_id")
    private Table2 table2;
}

@Entity  
@Table(name = "entity2")  
public class Entity2 {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity3_id")
    private Table3 table3;
}

@Entity  
@Table(name = "entity3")  
public class Entity3 {
    @Id
    private long id;
}
```

I need to all delete the occurencies of Entity1 when it joins Entity2 filtering by Entity3, like this:

```
em.createQuery("delete from Entity1 e where e.entity2.entity3 = :entity3")
```

And Hibernate generates the following SQL:

```
delete from entity1 cross join entity2 entity2_ where entity3_id=?
```

The problem is that PostgreSQL does not recognized the cross join and I didn't find any other way to do this (other than using native query).

PS: in the database all the tables have foreign keys.

Comment: please make sure that hibernate recognizes PostgreSQL database? is dialect correcty set? you should see that in logs when app is starting.

Comment: Yes, it recognizes. It is using PostgreSQL94Dialect by default. Other queries work, just some like this that not.

Answer (score 0):

Now I found that it's not possible to use joins in delete queries (actually a was migrating from EclipseLink to Hibernate and on EclipseLink it worked, just on Hibernate it doesn't).
[Hibernate Exception on MySQL Cross Join Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246563/hibernate-exception-on-mysql-cross-join-query)