# spring data jpa generate wrong sql

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Entity DSSchema:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DS_SCHEMA", schema = "DSUSER")
public class DSSchema {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "idGenerator", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "idGenerator")
    private String id;

}
```

Entity DSTableRelation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DS_TABLE_RELATION", schema = "DSUSER")
public class DSTableRelation {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "idGenerator", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "idGenerator")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SCHEMA_ID", nullable = false)
    private DSSchema schema;

}
```

Entity DSColumnRelation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DS_COLUMN_RELATION", schema = "DSUSER")
public class DSColumnRelation {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "idGenerator", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "idGenerator")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TABLE_RELATION_ID", nullable = false)
    private DSTableRelation tableRelation;

}
```

Repository DSColumnRelationRepository:

```
public interface DSColumnRelationRepository extends JpaRepository<DSColumnRelation, String> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from DSColumnRelation c where c.tableRelation.schema.id = ?1")
    void deleteBySchemaId(String schemaId);

}
```

Excute the method 'deleteBySchemaId', and check the generated sql:

```
delete 
from
    DSUSER.DS_COLUMN_RELATION cross 
join
    DSUSER.DS_TABLE_RELATION dstablerel1_ 
where
    SCHEMA_ID=?
```

this sql is wrong sql, please tell me why using spring data jpa cause error,thanks.

Comment: Since there is no field `tableRelation` on your candidate of `DSColumnRelation` then your JPQL makes no sense ... or maybe you have misposted those classes (`DSColumnRelation` with a table name of `DS_TABLE_RELATION` etc)

Comment: sorry, i wrote the wrong code, please see the newest

Comment: What's wrong with the generated sql?

Comment: the 'join ... on', 'on' and condition wasn't generated.

Comment: But it is `cross join` and `cross join` does not have an `on` clause. The problem is `delete` on a `join`.

Comment: What is your JPA provider?

Comment: hibernate is my JPA provider

Comment: i found a similar question 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246563/hibernate-exception-on-mysql-cross-join-query', doesn't hibernate support my delete ql ?