# How to access foreign key and its data in JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two entities as follows:

```java
public class EntityA
{
    private String id;
    private String entityId;
    private String muscle;
}

public class EntityB
{
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("entitya_id")
    private EntityA entitya;
}
```

Now in my `EntityB` repo class I am having a method to delete rows of Table EntityB based on EntityA fields.

```java
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM EntityB WHERE EntityA.entityId=:entityId AND (:muscle IS NULL OR EntityA.muscle=:muscle)")
int deleteEntityByRecords(@Param("entityId")  String entityId, 

@Param("muscle")String muscle);
```

But this query gives me an exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'EntityBrepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract int com.fedex.airops.pilot.bank.PilotBankTransactionRepo.deleteEntityBRecord(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query seems incorrect. Try below query:

```
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM EntityB eb WHERE eb.entitya.id=:entityId AND (:muscle IS NULL OR eb.entitya.muscle=:muscle)")
int deleteEntityByRecords(@Param("entityId")  String entityId, @Param("muscle") String muscle);
```

Comment: Jignesh i have edit the post, could you please give it a look, and suggest me how I can resolve

Comment: Can you post what exact query you have in repository.

Comment: Ya I see. May be this can work for you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7247124/3709922

Answer (score 1):

You can also JPA Repository:

```
void deleteByIdAndEntityAMuscleIsNullOrEntityAMuscle(@Param("entityId")  String entityId, @Param("muscle") String muscle);
```